Dlls & Memory Management
This is more of a general question and not specific. I am writing a dll in C++, there are C++ classes and some extern C-wrapper functions that handle the interaction between the client and the classes. I have a vector list of all the pointers to the objects that get created. My thinking was that I should put a function call in the dllmain.cpp file for the 'dll_process_detach' case that would delete all the objects once the dll shuts down. Here is the dllmain code with the function call in the dll_process_detach case.Do any of you see an issue with this approach ?
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include "libloaderapi.h"
#include "XTalk.h"
#include <vector>

// Entry-point function for the DLL application
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Code to run when the DLL is loaded
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // Code to run when a new thread is created
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        // Code to run when a thread ends normally
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // Code to run when the DLL is unloaded

        BasePin::deleteAllObjects(); 

        // If lpReserved is NULL, it means the DLL is being unloaded by FreeLibrary
        // If lpReserved is not NULL, it means the DLL is being unloaded due to process termination
        if (lpReserved == NULL)
        {
            // Unload the DLL if it was dynamically loaded using LoadLibrary
            //FreeLibrary(hModule);
        }

        break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Indicate that the DLL was successfully loaded/unloaded
}

I have the code written and as far as I can tell it seems to be running fine, but I want to know if this is in line with common practices or if I'm doing something foolish.

The process memory is going away and will be reclaimed by the OS.  You only need to clean-up objects that manage external resources eg close any files that wont be closed by RAII.

So is it useless to delete the objects then ?  Should I just not worry about it ? On the client side, once the objects are created they will not be deleted while the program is running.

You are keeping a singleton to manage the created objects any way. Make it a Meyers singleton and leave the cleanup to its destructor. That would be more consistent with static libraries, in case some later time you decide to make a static version.
